# Java Android - Force all audio to headphones

Tags: java, android, android-audiomanager, headphones

I've seen several examples of forcing audio to speakers while headphones are plugged in but what I'm trying to do is somewhat unique in that, I want to force audio to headphones when another media application would otherwise be sending that audio to your TV for example when casting to your TV via chromecast.

Is this possible?

Comment: I hope not.  An application should not be able to "take over" like that.

Comment: What makes you say that? Wouldn't that be a beneficial functionality in the case stated above? An application which you can open and select "Route audio to headphones" so you can watch neftlix on your TV without disturbing people that might be sleeping in the same room? Why shouldn't that be able to happen?